# Extract vimeo video Id from vimeo url objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, vimeo

I want to extract video id from a vimeo url, can any body help me with the RegEx for the same.

Video url can be of type

```
https://vimeo.com/173652088
```

this is just a sample url. RegEx should work for all vimeo urls.

Comment: is the video id coming at the end always? or what can be other formats?

Comment: Yes video Id is always at the end of the url.Ex- .com/videoId

Comment: then why you try reg ex , try simple replace occuring string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz try this code

```
NSString *yourStr = @"https://vimeo.com/173652088";
NSString *str = [yourStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"https://" withString:@""];

 NSArray *arryVedios =[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] ;

NSString *id= [ arryVedios lastObject];
 NSLog(@"id= %@",id);
```

this code work for every url.but your id must be in last.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *old  = @"https://vimeo.com/173652088";
NSString *new = [old stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"https://vimeo.com/" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"new= %@", new);

NSString *newone = [[old componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject];
 NSLog(@"newone= %@", newone);
```

[image]

Comment: if your url is dynamic then go for regex

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure it is a vimeo url then the following would work

```
[^\/]+(?=\/$|$)
```

online tester here 
[online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/rZ1cR0/1)

Also you can extract the lastComponent from the Url

```
 NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://vimeo.com/173031270"];
 NSLog(@video id: %@", url.lastPathComponent);
```

Note that this solution will fail if you have a url like "https://vimeo.com/173031270?a=1&b=2"